# matlab tall arrays with for loop inplementation

Tags: arrays, matlab, datastore

I'm working with binary data in large files (30GB+).
I have implemented fileDatastore with a custom read function.

```
fds = fileDatastore(location,'ReadFcn',@readFile);
```

The readFile function reads in the binary data into an array a byte at a time.
I then create a tall array from the fileDatastore.

```
data = tall(fds);
```

This all seems to be working fine. Now I would like to search through the tall array for a byte pattern (ex. 25 followed by 30).  Something like...

```
for i=1:size(data)
    if data(i) == 25 && data(i+1) == 30
        disp('do something')
    end
end
```

This does not seem to be possible.  I end up with a 'conversion to logical from tall is not possible' error.  How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Not directly relevant but you likely want `1:numel(data)` rather than `1:size(data)`

Comment: I don't have the toolbox to test myself, but I'd check out `class(data(i) == 25)` and `doc relop` for clues.  It's posible you need `and` (just one & instead of &&) for the data types you're dealing with.

Comment: Isn't it the case that operations on `tall` arrays are not performed until you `gather` the data? If you display `data(1)` do you see the value in the file or just a `?` question mark?

Comment: I would suggest reading the documentation on [Indexing and Viewing Tall Array Elements](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/index-and-view-tall-array-elements.html). `data(i)` is not going to return a double. As @Justin mentioned, you will likely need to use [`gather`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gather.html) to evaluate the indexing and bring the result into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what it seems you need to do is to iterate over subsets of your data since it is too bit to fit into memory. For instance, if you set

```
y = gather(data(1:100))
```

Then you can do the comparisons you want on y instead of data. The important point is that `y` must fit in memory, while `data` does not. So you probably can't  (for instance) set

`y = gather(data)`

Comment: Yes, this is the conclusion I'm coming to as well which makes me question the usefulness of Matlab's new data type, the tall arrays.  I suppose it is still easier than parsing the file manually.

Comment: The tall arrays are meant for situations where the data can't fit into memory. If the data DOES fit into memory, then you should not use them, as you will almost certainly pay a performance penalty when compared to just loading the data in a standard matrix

Answer (score 2):

As excaza mentions, the problem is that although `data(i) == 25` is valid, it is not returning a boolean. So you cannot apply the && operator. 
The simple solution seems to be to nest the if statements...

```
if data(i) == 25 
   if data(i+1) == 30
        disp('do something')
    end
end
```

Comment: '&&' is not the problem, or at least not the only problem.  From what I can tell, tall arrays do not work with ANY logical operators.  @bremen_matt solution does not work because there is still '=='.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you cannot use tall logicals as conditions in loop statements. This is why the error is "Conversion to logical from tall is not possible." So since `data(i) == 25` returns a tall logical, you just need to use `gather` to turn that into an in-memory logical. Try this instead (since it's probably more efficient to gather these at the same time):

```
[a,b] = gather(data(i)==25,data(i+1)==30);
if a && b
    disp('do something')
end
```

> Source:
>   http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/deferred-evaluation-of-tall-arrays.html
>
> "For example, you cannot control if or while loop statements using a tall logical array, but once the array is evaluated with gather it
>   becomes an in-memory logical value that you can use in these
>   contexts."